# Writing into CSV file using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, pyserial

Here some simple code I have written. Data is not accumulated in the CSV file;
can someone share code to read data from serial port and log this to a CSV file?

```
import serial
import csv
import string
import os
import time
import sys

def main():
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    count=0
    f=open("test.txt","w+");
    result = csv.writer(f,delimiter=',', dialect='excel-tab')

    result_statememt=("date","zenith","elevation","azimuth","conv_elevation");
    result.writerow(result_statememt)
    f.close()
    while(count<10):
        #time.sleep(60)
        ser=serial.Serial()
        ser.port=3
        ser.baudrate=9600
        ser.open()
        str=ser.read(50)
        val=str.split(":")
        lines=str.split("\r\n")
        count=count+1
        print count
        f=open("test.txt","a+")
        result=csv.writer(f,delimiter=',')
        result.writerow()
        f.close()

    f.close()
    ser.close()
```

Comment: `result.writerow()` is an error, you're not passing anything to it.

Answer (score 2):

As noted, since you're not passing anything to `result.writerow()` nothing is being written to the CSV file. But I'm also concerned that you're reading 50 bytes at a time from the serial port, then splitting it on the `:` character and then splitting it on a `\r\n` delimiter. I don't think this is going to do what you want.

My guess is that you are expecting the serial port to deliver lines terminated by `\r\n`, each line consisting of a set of fields separated by `:`, and you want to write these fields to a CSV file. I'd recommend trying something like this instead:

```
with open("test.txt", "wb") as output_file:
    csv_out = csv.writer(output_file, delimiter=',', dialect='excel-tab')
    csv_out.writerow("date","zenith","elevation","azimuth","conv_elevation")

    ser=serial.Serial(port=3, baudrate=9600, timeout=60)
    ser.open()
    for count in range(10):
        str = ser.readline().rstrip()
        csv_out.writerow(str.split(':'))
    ser.close()
```

I haven't used the Python `serial` module and don't currently have hardware to test this, but based on my reading of the module documentation this should be closer to what you want to do. I *think* the read timeout is measured in seconds, so this will time out if the serial port doesn't produce any data for one minute.

Comment: What's `rtrim()`? Perhaps you mean `rstrip()`?

Comment: Ack, yes, I did. Apparently some repressed PHP memory rose up when I wasn't looking. Fixing, thanks.